# Is there a way to refresh the directive in ionic 3?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3

I have a `Directive` and I have one method called `startCountDown()`. Using a selector that directive is called in almost all components. Now, when I do `platform.pause` (app goes in background) and when I come in foreground, the countdown timer is not getting refreshed.

This is for ionic3 directive, in `platform.resume` function, I have already passed the details from where the timer shall start. But still on `platform.resume` its not showing updated countdown.

```
if (this.plt.resume.emit) {
    this.platformResume = this.plt.resume.subscribe((result) => {
        this.gameDateTime = this.fixture.gameDateTime;

    });
}

<div class="match_timer">
    <match-timer duration="{{gameDateTime}}"></match-timer>
</div>
```

When I am putting app on background for 5 mins and current time remaining is 10 mins. When I come in foreground the countdown must start from 5 mins. Not 8 or 9 mins

Comment: @PankajParkar, can you please help me on this.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: @estus hey can you please help me here